# How can I fill multiple colors in a path for SVG?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg

I'm using a path with default fill color of white. I display the path by storing it in object for example:

I have object named: **svg_path**

```
svg_path: "M 249.00,4.80 C 290.13,4.93 329.59,13.62 366.00,33.31 392.61,47.70 415.78,66.26 435.71,89.00 513.68,177.94 515.13,312.55 440.74,404.00 420.15,429.31 394.70,450.17 366.00,465.69 333.17,483.45 295.30,493.58 258.00,494.00 258.00,494.00 234.00,494.00 234.00,494.00 213.63,493.76 183.16,486.19 164.00,479.05 131.25,466.84 100.84,447.67 76.09,422.91 4.06,350.88 -15.12,241.71 25.86,149.00 53.48,86.53 109.78,36.32 175.00,16.02 191.65,10.85 218.73,5.03 236.00,4.80 236.00,4.80 249.00,4.80 249.00,4.80 Z M 340.00,160.00 C 340.00,160.00 300.00,119.00 300.00,119.00 297.32,116.32 288.38,106.20 285.00,106.20 281.69,106.20 272.60,116.32 270.04,119.00 270.04,119.00 231.00,162.00 231.00,162.00 231.00,162.00 250.00,161.00 250.00,161.00 250.00,161.00 263.00,161.00 263.00,161.00 263.00,161.00 263.00,175.00 263.00,175.00 263.00,175.00 264.00,197.00 264.00,197.00 264.00,197.00 146.00,197.00 146.00,197.00 146.00,197.00 145.00,219.00 145.00,219.00 145.00,219.00 145.00,237.00 145.00,237.00 145.00,237.00 168.00,237.00 168.00,237.00 168.00,237.00 185.00,238.00 185.00,238.00 185.00,238.00 306.00,238.00 306.00,238.00 306.00,238.00 306.00,161.00 306.00,161.00 306.00,161.00 340.00,160.00 340.00,160.00 Z M 307.00,387.00 C 307.00,387.00 361.00,345.58 361.00,345.58 364.52,342.69 377.49,333.73 375.83,329.00 374.51,325.21 362.60,315.49 359.00,312.42 359.00,312.42 328.00,287.00 328.00,287.00 321.92,282.23 313.29,275.30 306.00,273.00 306.00,273.00 306.00,309.00 306.00,309.00 306.00,309.00 145.00,309.00 145.00,309.00 145.00,309.00 145.00,350.00 145.00,350.00 145.00,350.00 214.00,350.00 214.00,350.00 214.00,350.00 231.00,349.00 231.00,349.00 231.00,349.00 268.00,349.00 268.00,349.00 268.00,349.00 296.00,349.00 296.00,349.00 298.60,349.01 302.42,348.67 304.42,350.60 307.07,353.15 306.99,360.49 307.00,364.00 307.00,364.00 307.00,387.00 307.00,387.00 Z"
```

this code is equivalent of 2 arrows inside a circle.

What I want to happened is:

1. fill the CIRCLE color to **white**
2. fill the STRAIGHT arrow to **green**
3. fill the CURVED arrow to **orange**

Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: You might be able to use a linearGradient depending on where the bits are located but it's far far easier just to have 3 separate paths and colour them each individually.

Comment: @RobertLongson that was the problem, I only need to use one path because i'm using this path in vue2-google-map package.

Comment: were the curves around along the arrows intentional, or just a result of you using only cubic curves to describe straight lines? if so, check this path out: `"M 250.1 4.8 A 240 240 0 1 1 249.9 4.8 Z M 340,160 285,106.2 231,162 263,161 264,197 146,197 146,238 306,238 306,161 Z M 307,387 375.83,329 306,273 306,309 145,309 145,350 304.42,350.60Z"`

Comment: If you intend to use this svg inside a map (gmap or mapbox), I'd advice you to look into geojsons instead that would fit to your needs more accurately. And you'd be able to style each element separately through the map's api
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson

Answer (score 1):

Well you should really be drawing this as three paths. But if you want a hack - here's a hack using filters:

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1600px" height="800px">
  <defs>
    <filter id="quilt-fill" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood x="7%" y="10%" width="15%" height="20%" flood-color="green" result="straight"/>
      <feFlood x="7%" y="32%" width="18%" height="20%" flood-color="orange" result="curved"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="straight"/>
        <feMergeNode in="curved"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g filter="url(#quilt-fill">
  <path fill="white" fill-rule="even-odd" d="M 249.00,4.80 C 290.13,4.93 329.59,13.62 366.00,33.31 392.61,47.70 415.78,66.26 435.71,89.00 513.68,177.94 515.13,312.55 440.74,404.00 420.15,429.31 394.70,450.17 366.00,465.69 333.17,483.45 295.30,493.58 258.00,494.00 258.00,494.00 234.00,494.00 234.00,494.00 213.63,493.76 183.16,486.19 164.00,479.05 131.25,466.84 100.84,447.67 76.09,422.91 4.06,350.88 -15.12,241.71 25.86,149.00 53.48,86.53 109.78,36.32 175.00,16.02 191.65,10.85 218.73,5.03 236.00,4.80 236.00,4.80 249.00,4.80 249.00,4.80 Z M 340.00,160.00 C 340.00,160.00 300.00,119.00 300.00,119.00 297.32,116.32 288.38,106.20 285.00,106.20 281.69,106.20 272.60,116.32 270.04,119.00 270.04,119.00 231.00,162.00 231.00,162.00 231.00,162.00 250.00,161.00 250.00,161.00 250.00,161.00 263.00,161.00 263.00,161.00 263.00,161.00 263.00,175.00 263.00,175.00 263.00,175.00 264.00,197.00 264.00,197.00 264.00,197.00 146.00,197.00 146.00,197.00 146.00,197.00 145.00,219.00 145.00,219.00 145.00,219.00 145.00,237.00 145.00,237.00 145.00,237.00 168.00,237.00 168.00,237.00 168.00,237.00 185.00,238.00 185.00,238.00 185.00,238.00 306.00,238.00 306.00,238.00 306.00,238.00 306.00,161.00 306.00,161.00 306.00,161.00 340.00,160.00 340.00,160.00 Z M 307.00,387.00 C 307.00,387.00 361.00,345.58 361.00,345.58 364.52,342.69 377.49,333.73 375.83,329.00 374.51,325.21 362.60,315.49 359.00,312.42 359.00,312.42 328.00,287.00 328.00,287.00 321.92,282.23 313.29,275.30 306.00,273.00 306.00,273.00 306.00,309.00 306.00,309.00 306.00,309.00 145.00,309.00 145.00,309.00 145.00,309.00 145.00,350.00 145.00,350.00 145.00,350.00 214.00,350.00 214.00,350.00 214.00,350.00 231.00,349.00 231.00,349.00 231.00,349.00 268.00,349.00 268.00,349.00 268.00,349.00 296.00,349.00 296.00,349.00 298.60,349.01 302.42,348.67 304.42,350.60 307.07,353.15 306.99,360.49 307.00,364.00 307.00,364.00 307.00,387.00 307.00,387.00 Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```